Angular SSO not making it to identity login page
Currently trying to get my Angular app to SSO login with the Duende Identity server that I created. I'm able to hit everything in postman and login and get a token. Now I am trying to get the same results with the Angular app but when I click the login button I get the following error. I'm using the angular-oauth2-oidc package to make this simpler. I have posted the code that I have and cant seem to see why I can hit the login screen of the Identity server.
the correct link is /Account/Login but It never makes it there.
makes it here when I get the error:
http://localhost:5000/home/error?errorId=CfDJ8OrrbCpIWPdCjNyK...
Error
Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request
Request Id: 0HN3B2BKF8VK6:00000001


sso.config.ts
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

  export const authCodeFlowConfig: AuthConfig = {      
  issuer: 'http://localhost:5000',
  clientId: 'nextApp',
  responseType: 'code',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  // dummyClientSecret: 'secret',
  scope: 'openid profile auctionApp',
  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false, 
  skipIssuerCheck: true,
  showDebugInformation: true,
};

Update: So when I change the redirectUri: window.location.origin to redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/api/auth/callback', im able to reach the Login page and login while getting the token back. but I get redirect to  http://localhost:4200/api/auth/callback?iss=identity-svc when what I really want is just http://localhost:4200. not finding away to get the url right.
HeaderComponent.ts
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{


constructor(private router: Router,private oauthService: OAuthService) 
{ 
  this.configureSingleSignOn(); 
}

configureSingleSignOn()
{
  this.oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
  this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();     
} 

login() {
   this.oauthService.initLoginFlow();           
}

HeaderComponent.html
 <li class="nav-item">
    <button class="nav-link" (click)="login()">LogIn</button>
 </li>

Asp.Net Core Identity service config.cs
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new IdentityResource[]
        {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new ApiScope[]
        {
            new ApiScope("auctionApp", "Auciton app full access"),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients(IConfiguration config) =>
        new Client[]
        {        
            // interactive client using code flow + pkce
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "postman",
                ClientName = "postman",
                AllowedScopes = {"openid","profile", "auctionApp"},
                RedirectUris = {"https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"},
                ClientSecrets = new [] {new Secret("NotASecret".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = {GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword}
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "nextApp",
                ClientName = "nextApp",
                ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
                RequirePkce = false,
                RedirectUris = {config["ClientApp"] + "/api/auth/callback/id-server"},
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = {"openid", "profile", "auctionApp"},
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600*24*30,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
            }
        };
}

HostingExtentionss.cs With CORS
internal static class HostingExtensions
{
    public static WebApplication ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); 

        builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        builder.Services
            .AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                if (builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("Docker"))
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = "identity-svc";
                }

                // see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/
                //options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients(builder.Configuration))
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();

        builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            //for using HTTP
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        });

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
            

        return builder.Build();
    }

    public static WebApplication ConfigurePipeline(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()                              
                                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")); 
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages()
            .RequireAuthorization();

        return app;
    }
}


I understand what you're trying to do. I'd like to suggest these steps for your problem:

Client Configuration Verification:

Match Client ID and Redirect URI:
Ensure the clientId in sso.config.ts ("nextApp") matches the ClientId in your Duende Identity Server config.cs for the "nextApp" client.
Verify the redirectUri in sso.config.ts matches the RedirectUris configured for the "nextApp" client in config.cs. Include the correct port and path if applicable.

Grant Type Correction:

Change Login Function:
Update your HeaderComponent.ts login() function to use this.oauthService.initLoginFlow() instead of this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow(). This is necessary for code flow with PKCE as configured in your sso.config.ts.
TypeScript
HeaderComponent.ts
login() {
  this.oauthService.initLoginFlow(); // Use initLoginFlow for code flow
}


Scope Verification:

Compare Allowed Scopes:
Ensure the scopes requested in sso.config.ts ("openid", "profile", "auctionApp") are also included in the allowed scopes for the "nextApp" client in your config.cs.

CORS Configuration (if applicable):

Enable CORS for Angular Domain:
If your Angular application is hosted on a different domain than your Duende Identity Server, configure CORS in your Identity Server to allow requests from your Angular application's domain.
Additional Steps:
Enable Debug Logs:
Set showDebugInformation: true in sso.config.ts to get detailed logs about the OAuth2 flow and identify potential issues with request parameters or responses.
Inspect Network Traffic:
Use browser developer tools to analyze network requests and responses during the login flow. Look for errors or unexpected behavior.
Compare with Postman:
Compare the requests sent from Postman during successful login with those sent from your Angular application. Identify any discrepancies in parameters or headers.
